# Setting up pincone for autogpt

Tags: artificial-intelligence, autogpt

I'm trying to setup `AutoGPT` with a `Pinecone` database for extended memory, but I'm getting the below errors. I have an index, collection, and API key set up for it in Pinecone and in the env file. Yes, I have confirmed the index name.

```py
Connecting Pinecone. This may take some time... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 419, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1075, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\utils\error_handling.py", line 17, in inner_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pinecone\index.py", line 329, in delete    
    return self._vector_api.delete(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py", line 776, in __call__
    return self.callable(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api\vector_operations_api.py", line 117, in __delete
    return self.call_with_http_info(**kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py", line 838, in call_with_http_info
    return self.api_client.call_api(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py", line 413, in call_api
    return self.__call_api(resource_path, method,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py", line 200, in __call_api
    response_data = self.request(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\api_client.py", line 459, in request
    return self.rest_client.POST(url,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\rest.py", line 271, in POST
    return self.request("POST", url,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\client\rest.py", line 157, in request
    r = self.pool_manager.request(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 78, in request   
    return self.request_encode_body(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 376, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 419, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1075, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\dev\autogpt\Auto-GPT\autogpt\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    autogpt.cli.main()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1130, in __call__     
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1635, in invoke       
    rv = super().invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke       
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke        
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 26, in new_func 
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\dev\autogpt\Auto-GPT\autogpt\cli.py", line 90, in main
    run_auto_gpt(
    memory = get_memory(cfg, init=True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\dev\autogpt\Auto-GPT\autogpt\memory\__init__.py", line 49, in get_memory
    memory.clear()
  File "C:\dev\autogpt\Auto-GPT\autogpt\memory\pinecone.py", line 61, in clear
    self.index.delete(deleteAll=True)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pinecone\core\utils\error_handling.py", line 25, in inner_func
    raise PineconeProtocolError(f'Failed to connect; did you specify the correct index name?') from e
pinecone.core.exceptions.PineconeProtocolError: Failed to connect; did you specify the correct index name?
```

I tried running it and I was expecting it to successfully connect but got the stated error. I confirmed the env variables but no joy

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue when I uploaded environment variables with

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

and call

```
pinecone.init()
```

instead I did this:

```
import os

pinecone_api_key = os.getenv("PINECONE_API_KEY")
pinecone_index = os.getenv("PINECONE_INDEX")
pinecone_env = os.getenv("PINECONE_ENV")

pinecone.init(api_key=pinecone_api_key, environment=pinecone_env)
```